# Credit card regex not working in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, validation

I am using the following regex to validate the credit card number for various credit card types:

`/^((5[1-5]\d{14})|(4\d{12}(\d{3})?)|(3[47]\d{13})|(6011\d{14})|((30[0-5]|36\d|38\d)\d{11}))(?<=\d)$/`

This works as expected using online validators such as regex101.com but as soon as I am trying to use it with ngPattern it does not validate as expected. Basically, it allows to enter characters as well even though the regex would not allow that.

Sample:
http://plnkr.co/edit/r6qGoyfKHnzoOQmv0kpv

```
<input type="text" name='cc' ng-model="usd" ng-pattern="/^(5[1-5]\d{14})|(4\d{12}(\d{3})?)|(3[47]\d{13})|(6011\d{14})|((30[0-5]|36\d|38\d)\d{11})$/" 
   placeholder="credit card number"/>
```

Try enter the Visa test card number with some characters at the end.

Any help on this appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put everything into a group:

```
^(?:(5[1-5]\d{14})|(4\d{12}(\d{3})?)|(3[47]\d{13})|(6011\d{14})|((30[0-5]|36\d|38\d)\d{11}))$
 ^^^                                                                                       ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hV1zF3/1)

The problem arose because the `^` and `$` anchors *only applied to the first and last alternatives respectively*.

Adding the outer group (it can be capturing or non-capturing, in AngularJS it does not matter much) will make sure the start and end anchors will be applied to the whole regex pattern.